# combining SSD and hard disk in software RAID1?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, software-raid, raid-1

Does it make sense to build a Linux software RAID-1 (mirroring) using an SSD and a normal hard disk? I want to combine the advantages of SSD (fast transfer rates, fast access times) with the advantages of hard disks (cheap, different fault model) and get a very fast yet reliable RAID...

- does this actually make sense?
- is the SSD performance actually available in such a mixed setup? I.e. does Linux mainly use SSD for reading, or will it use the slow disk equally much?

Comment: see also; http://superuser.com/questions/242812/hybrid-ssd-hdd-raid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use the speed of an SSD + two HDD in RAID 1](https://superuser.com/questions/663509/use-the-speed-of-an-ssd-two-hdd-in-raid-1)

Answer (score 16):

Looks like this setup is quite ok. The basic rule is to use `mdadm` with `--write-mostly` parameter so that writes go to HDD. Reading will still be done from fast SSD. Also, the `--write-behind` parameter is said to improve write performance.

Support for TRIM command in such a setup appears to be a problem, though.

Further keywords for searching:

- `linux ssd raid hybrid`
- `mdadm "--write-mostly" ssd`

Further links:

- http://www.tansi.org/hybrid/ ("Hybrid HDD + SSD RAID1")
- http://linuxwiki.de/SSD (overview, hints; in German)
- http://marc.info/?l=linux-raid&m=126496930530289&w=2 ("SSD & mechanical disc in RAID 1")

Comment: +1. But remember that `--write-behind` is not safe, and because it needs a write-intent bitmap file external to the array it complicates setup and I wouldn't recommend it. `--write-mostly` is fine.

Answer (score 4):

The raid software will likely distribute the reads across the disks*. Given the read speed on the SSD is likely to be more than twice as fast as the slow disk, I would assume that you'd actually lose performance.

By your comment on fault model, I assume that you're concerned about the "wear out" rates of SSDs. Modern controllers use sophisticated [wear levelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling), so as long as you have a fair amount of free space on the drive mass amounts of writing isn't going to kill the drive any time soon.

*Edit:
According to the answer at [What advantages and disadvantages have Hybrid SSD/HDD RAIDs](https://superuser.com/questions/242812/hybrid-ssd-hdd-raid), it seems there are raid controllers/software that will intelligently bias the reads towards the SSD, so you won't lose performance by raiding it.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Also, "hybrid" is exactly the keyword whuch turns up more information in google - thanks a lot!

Comment: Regarding wear leveling: It's true that it's unlikely to lose data on SSD due to "wear out" of flash blocks. However the controller and wear-leveling data itself is a single point of failure. Just assume your SSD controller board dies; you will likely be unable to recover any data even if it's physically still there. So SSD wear-leveling does not replace real mirroring.