# Can I tell who manufactured my SSD?

Tags: linux, ssd

I bought a SSD from a national reseller who sold it under its own brand. But I know they did not manufacture it.

Since [my SSD is apparently failing](https://superuser.com/questions/1337564/is-my-ssd-drive-failing), I’d like to use a dedicated diagnostic tool. But I ask the reseller and they replied there is no dedicated diagnostic tool for this SSD and they won’t tell me who manufactured it.

My guess is that, if I knew who manufactured it, I could use their own diagnostic tool with my SSD, to check its health status. It might also be able to decode the S.M.A.R.T. attributes that smartmontools doesn’t know.

For what it’s worth, I’m using Debian GNU/Linux and have no license for any recent Windows (latest I have is Windows 98).

**Edit:** [According to the reseller](https://www.ldlc.com/fiche/PB00212817.html) (sorry, the link is in French), this device uses a SMI2256K controller. Can this information help?

Comment: Answered over there [How to see disk details like manufacturer in Linux - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/how-to-see-disk-details-like-manufacturer-in-linux)

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for pointing that U&L question. Unfortunately, all the suggestions only lead to the name of the reseller, not to that of the real manufacturer.

Comment: Not Sure but you may try your luck with this : **`dmidecode --type memory`**

Comment: @C0deDaedalus I just tried; it only gave me some information about the RAM.

Answer (score 2):

If there is an FCC ID number on it, you can check it here: https://www.fcc.gov/oet/ea/fccid

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. How/where would I find a FCC ID number? On on sticker or by software means? (I’m not very confident since that reseller doesn’t sell in the US.)

Comment: FCC ID should on be on the sticker glued to device.

Answer (score 0):

If your reseller repogrammed the firmware and added his name and model, than there's no easy way you can find out - there's no API that distinguishes between "reseller name/model" and "original manufacturer name/model".

If you had a database of all common SSD controllers, maybe there are some tests that one could use to narrow it down, but I don't know of any such public database.

And even if you knew the manufacturer, it's unlikely they would provide you with the low-level tools needed for such a task. After all, they gain nothing from it.

The "dedicated tools" that some SSD manufacturers offer for download don't go that deep.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable internal information of HDD/SSD can be extracted with [smartmontools](https://www.smartmontools.org/) as you mentioned. The only thing that one need to keep in mind, is that hardware database isn't always recent and need to be periodically updated with `update-smart-drivedb` that comes with smartmontools package on Debian(according to SMART info you posted in another thread, your database is dated as 2014-10-07). Database distributed as a simple C language header and on Debian should be located by default in `/var/lib/smartmontools/drivedb/drivedb.h`, so as a first step - update `drivedb.h` with `update-smart-drivedb(8)` and try to get full information with:

```
smartctl -a /dev/sdb
```

All information you are looking written in an internal EPROM on SSD controller, so it is the only info regarding  manufacturer. If reseller has capability (or agreement with original manufacturer) to change information in SMART report then you can't do anything about it. The only information you can get regarding original manufacturer is to find pattern in device numbering to compare with original manufacturer and hope that you guessed it right.

Regarding the issue of your SSD, practically all SSD/HDD manufacturers having spare cells on their device and replaced broken one when some threshold (usually pretty high) will be triggered and then internal controller will replace bad sectors, so they not willing to change bad sectors ASAP. On regular HDD you can  enforce internal controller's logic to replace bad sectors by writing repeatedly to broken sectors until it trigger replacement algorithm. Unfortunately it isn't a case with SSD where all sectors are virtual because internal controller always remapping cells to be able to redistribute write cycles (SSD killers) evenly across all cells, so practically it is impossible to cure such SSD by utilizing standard equipment. (Well, if there is important info that need to be restored, you can try to write 0(zero)/1(one) pattern to the whole disk and check after each pass if "196 Reallocated_Event_Count" changed. Just be warned, such procedure usually is 50/50 chance and can trigger either relocation of bad sectors or can do even worse)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ran `update-smart-drivedb` but, as far as I can tell, the output of `smartctl -a` did not change. Don’t I have to recompile smartctl? I tried to visually compare the list of attributes with those in the database. It looks like it might match the "Innodisk 3IE2/3ME2/3MG2/3SE2 SSDs" device. Might it be a hint?

Comment: @user2233709 You don't need to recompile smartctl, it picks fresh data from drivedb.h on loading and parsing internally. And yes, it could be a hint if some "unknown" parameters exist and such parameters exist in another devices.

Comment: BTW, try -P option, `smartctl -a -P showall /dev/sdb`, does it uncover any additional info ?