# AMD RAID Configuration SSD+HDD

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, raid

I bought a new components for my HTPC. I bought a GA-F2A88XN-WIFI, a Kingston Fury 120 GB SSD and 2x Seagate Barracuda **3TB** disks. The idea was to use SSD for OS and applications and 2x 3TB HDDs in RAID0 for storage.

I plugged the HW the following way:
 Port0 SSD
 Port1 LG BlueRay, DVD, CD ROM
 Port2 and Port3 Seagate's HDDs

When I choose RAID as controller in BIOS, I can enter the RAID configuration and create an array from disk 2 and 3 (HDDs) but it only gives me 2.1TB total. Also, when I reboot, I no longer see SSD in the list of boot options, therefore, I cannot install the OS.

I have no idea how to make this work. I would really appreciate the help.

On a different topic, I bought Kingston HyperX Savage 2.8GB 2400mhz memory. When I select XMP profile 1 for 2400 settings, the pc won't boot and I have to load bios defaults to make it boot at least to BIOS. XMP profile 2 2133mhz works fine. Why is this happening?

Comment: 2.1TB is probably 2.0 TiB. Max size for an MBR formatted disk

Comment: If you set the BIOS to normal AHCI (not fake RAID) mode and install the OS then you can creata RAID array from there. You did not mention which OS you used, but for Linux look at mda. For windows look in diskmanager. It will complain about needing danamic disks and not being able to boot from it, but with the OS on the SSD that is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
To configure SATA hard drive(s), follow the steps below:
A. Install SATA hard drive(s) in your computer.
B. Configure SATA controller mode in BIOS Setup.
C. Configure a RAID array in RAID BIOS (Note 1)
D. Install the SATA RAID/AHCI driver and operating system (Note 2)
```

And:

```
Step 1:
You need to install the SATA RAID/AHCI driver during the OS installation. Use an alternative system to copy
the SATA RAID/AHCI driver from the motherboard driver disk to a USB flash drive. Copy the Hw8_A88 folder
under BootDrv in the driver disk.
```

Boot from your windows disk as normal, then load the RAID drivers from an alternative media source (USB Key) during the install process.